# Not able to extract Values from XML using Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to extract one of the objects from an XML object using Jaxb. It doesn't return with any error log. But, it returns a null object. Please find the code. Kindly let me know only with Jaxb(Not with Documentbuilder way)

### XML string (ResponseXML)

```
 <DATAPACKET REQUEST-ID = "4">
 <HEADER>
     <RESPONSE-TYPE CODE = "0" DESCRIPTION = "Response Error" />
 </HEADER>
 <BODY>
     <ERROR-LIST>
        <ERROR-CODE>107</ERROR-CODE>
     </ERROR-LIST>
 </BODY>
 </DATAPACKET>
```

DataPacket

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
 @XmlRootElement(name = "DATAPACKET")
 public class DataPacket {    

 @XmlElement(name ="BODY")
 private Body BODY;

 public DataPacket (){}

 // Setter and getter of Body  

 }
```

Body

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Body{    

@XmlElement(name ="ERROR-LIST")
private ErrorListDto errorList;

 public Body(){}
 // Setter and getter of errorList
 }
```

ErrorListDto

```
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
 public class ErrorListDto{    

 @XmlElement(name="ERROR-CODE")
 private List<ErrorCodesDto> errorCodes;

 public ErrorListDto(){}

 // Setter and getter of errorCodes   
 }
```

ErrorCodesDto

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ErrorCodesDto {

@XmlElement(name = "ERROR-CODE")
private String ERROR_CODE;

public ErrorCodesDto() {}
```

Im extracting the values as follows

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(DataPacket.class);
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
 StringReader reader = new StringReader(responseXML);
 DataPacket dp = (DataPacket) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);                       
 Body body = dp.getBODY();
 ErrorListDto errorList = body.getErrorList();
 System.out.println(errorList.toString()); --> Here it has error code as null
```

Please let me know what is going on wrong here. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Guillem, do you have any idea on this?

Comment: I suggest that you do the reverse to find out what's going wrong. Try instantiating DataPacket along with Body and ErrorList and then serialize and dump it somewhere to view the output.

Comment: Is your class Datapacket even compiling? It has a body constructor instead of DataPacket. Also your error code and ErrorList are represented by same class..

Comment: @Optional, It was a typo. Updated with the code.  yes its compiling. No compile time errors. You can copy the code and test.

Comment: @Optional, can you please check now. May be I have missed something while copy and paste of code.

Comment: @Optional, if you feel there is an typo, please let me know. In my code base, there are no compile time errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `ErrorCodesDto` as below and it shall work:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class ErrorCodesDto {

    @XmlValue
    private String ERROR_CODE;

    public ErrorCodesDto() {
    }

}
```

Otherwise your expected "xml" shall contain

```
 <ERROR-LIST>
        <ERROR-CODE><ERROR-CODE>107</ERROR-CODE></ERROR-CODE>
</ERROR-LIST>
```

To answer your comment, the code works even with following xml

```
<DATAPACKET REQUEST-ID = "4">
 <HEADER>
     <RESPONSE-TYPE CODE = "0" DESCRIPTION = "Response Error" />
 </HEADER>
 <BODY>
     <ERROR-LIST>
        <ERROR-CODE>107</ERROR-CODE>
        <ERROR-CODE>108</ERROR-CODE>
        <ERROR-CODE>109</ERROR-CODE>
     </ERROR-LIST>
 </BODY>
 </DATAPACKET>
```

> Edit

You can also achieve this without the `ErrorCodesDto` class as well by just changing `ErrorListDto` to have

```
@XmlElement(name = "ERROR-CODE") 
private List<String> errorCodes;
```

Comment: That is fine, your error code list s part of  `ErrorListDto` where it is declared as List.

Comment: My error list will be like ERROR-LIST>
        <ERROR-CODE>107</ERROR-CODE><ERROR-CODE>108</ERROR-CODE>
     </ERROR-LIST>

Comment: Did you test my code first? I just edited the answer with exact same xml and it works. Your ERROR-CODE is a value element and not a complex element.

Comment: Just a min. I will test and let you know.

Comment: After you test, did you realize, you can achieve this without the `ErrorCodesDto` class as well by just changing `ErrorListDto` to `@XmlElement(name = "ERROR-CODE")
    private List<String> errorCodes;`

Comment: Yes. I just checked with that code and it works very charm.